# how to transfer server ownership on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm new at making discord bots and I want to know how to make a transfer ownership command, is there a way for that?
Thank's for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should know that a transfer of ownership is only possible, if the bot is the current owner of ther server. So the bot can't transfer the ownership from own member to another. (source: [discord.py-docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.edit)

Answer (score 0):

To change the ownership of the server, the bot should be the owner of the server.

You can find more detail on this : [How to transfer a discord server ownership with a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835140/how-to-transfer-a-discord-server-ownership-with-a-bot)

Answer (score 0):

You should transfer discord server: https://discord.onl/2019/02/03/how-to-transfer-discord-server-ownership/